# Fail to use std::get to reach tuple element

Tags: c++, stl, stdtuple

### Original post:

I am having an object in a complex project. So I may not be able to provide very detail API of all these classes, but I am trying to abstract my problem without need of detail.

First of all, the code below works fine:

```
auto ha = std::get< 1 >( d.data ).data;
```

Then I am try to have code below:

```
auto ha = std::get< 1 >( d.data ).data;
int ma = ha;
```

The compiler says

```
cannot convert ‘std::tuple<>’ to ‘int’ in initialization int ma = ha;
cannot convert ‘std::tuple<PointStreamColor<float> >’ to ‘int’ in initialization
```

This should means that `ha` is a std::tuple variable. Then I have code below:

```
auto ha = std::get< 1 >( d.data ).data;
auto ma = std::get< 0 >( ha );
```

For the code above, the compiler says

```
no matching function for call to ‘get(std::tuple<>&)’ int ma = std::get< 0 >( ha );
```

I cannot understand why can't I use std::get here to reach the first element of a std::tuple? Can anyone give me some idea?

### Update

Thank you all for pointing out that I should provide more info. I totally understand this before I post. But the implementation of classes here are 
template based, so massive and hierarchical, that I am not able to provide them all.

So I was trying to ask for any general idea that might cause failure for reaching `std::tuple` element by `std::get`.

Maybe the problem I am facing is not suitable for public discusstion here. I am so sorry for taking your time. I cannot delete this question now and maybe one of you can help close this question now.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is `d`? , what is `data`? You need to provide a [MCVE].

Comment: "Can anyone give me some idea?" Don't you think it would be a good idea to at least provide that tuple definition? Our telepathy machine is broken today, sorry.

Comment: Guessing at what variables are with error messages is a... _curious_ way of programming .

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thank you Jabberwocky because I thought std::get should work for tuple anyway, so I did not attach the detail. I will add it soon.

Comment: @SummerSun OK, and please keep it minimal.

Comment: I'm sorry @Jabberwocky and all, I fail to provide detail info due to the complexity of codes. Maybe you can help me close this question now. I apologize for posting this stupid question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the zeroth element from a tuple with no elements.

It's the same concept as indexing an empty array at 0.

EDIT: To clarify, I suspect your code is being called twice. The line

```
auto ha = std::get< 1 >( d.data ).data;
int ma = ha;
```

gives two error messages, because in both cases, `ha` is a tuple, which can't cast to an int:

```
cannot convert ‘std::tuple<>’ to ‘int’ in initialization int ma = ha;
cannot convert ‘std::tuple<PointStreamColor<float> >’ to ‘int’ in initialization
```

This shows in the first case, ha is an empty tuple. In the second case, ha has one element.

The alternative code

```
auto ha = std::get< 1 >( d.data ).data;
auto ma = std::get< 0 >( ha );
```

only results in one error message because `std::get< 0 >( ha )` is perfectly valid in the second case, when `ha` is type `std::tuple<PointStreamColor<float> >` which has one element. This error message arises from the first case, when `ha` is type `std::tuple<>` which is empty:

```
no matching function for call to ‘get(std::tuple<>&)’ int ma = std::get< 0 >( ha );
```

Comment: How do you know that there is a tuple with no elements involved?

Comment: @Slava: Because of the error: no matching function for call to ‘get(std::tuple<>&)’

Comment: Thank you for your idea, but here I truly have one element and it can be seen from debugger.

Comment: @SummerSun: Thanks for clarifying, I've updated my answer to explain why.